# Не удаётся вывести данные из сущности

Tags: java, spring-boot

Никак не удаётся вывести на экран квартиры из сущности House всем списком и отдельно по ID. Когда перехожу на страницу, то выдаёт ошибку, что бесконечный цикл

```
Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: task.homerent.model.House["city"]->task.homerent.model.City$HibernateProxy$ikPQOTJQ["house"])
```

Ссылка на [код](https://github.com/Blacit/HomeRent.git)

Вот так выглядит Контроллер:

```
HouseRestController


@GetMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:read')")
    public House userPostInfo(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        Optional<House> house = houseRepository.findById(id);
        List<House> res = new ArrayList<>();
        house.ifPresent(res::add);

        return res.stream().filter(houses -> houses.getId().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что при сериализации у вас возникла бесконечная зависимости `house->city->house`.

Вам нужно разрешить эту зависимость, например так:

```
public class City {
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<House> house;
}

public class House {
    @JsonManagedReference
    private City city;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113474/discussion-on-answer-by-komdosh------).